# Using jquery to addClass if known URL with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I'm using Ruby on Rails to develop an application. I have included a set of links for my pages (using partials), I'd like to add a class `active` when someone visits a page.

So if I have links like this: (this is included in all pages, to make pages cleaner)

```
<ul>
<li><a href="profile">Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="profile/users">Users</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have jQuery:

```
var loc = window.location.pathname;
var href = ??
if(loc == href){
 var thisli = $('href').parents('li');
 $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

I'm still figuring out how would I do such a thing? Unless there's another way? I'm used to working with PHP, so I'm not familiar if rails has any other easier way to add an active class to a link that someone is currently visiting.

Thanks!

Comment: your jquery seems all messed up. $('href') should be, I'm assuming, $('a');. and what are you expecting $(this) to be? from the shown code, it looks like it might be the global scope (window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
$(function(){
    $('a[href="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

With javascript/jQuery, you can check the current URL path, with `window.location.pathname` and compare that with the link. Using an `a` element, you can compare absolute URLs.

To compare two URLs, we have to do a little additional work. Basic idea is create another [hidden] `a` element, set the href of that element to the test URL, and then see if their two resulting absolute URLs match.

So first:

```
function compareURLs(url1, url2) {
    var testElement = $('<a href=""></a>'),
        result1, result2;
    testElement.attr('href', url1);
    result1 = testElement.get(0).href;
    testElement.attr('href', url2);
    result2 = testElement.get(0).href;
    return result1 == result2;
}
```

Then to check each `a` element:

```
var path = window.locaion.pathname;
$('ul a').each(function() {
    if (compareURLs(path, $(this).attr('href')) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
}
```